# spring boot authorization server wildcard redirection list

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, angular-oauth2-oidc

I'm currently migrating my oauth server to the [Spring Authorization Server](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server) and want to use the code workflow. My frontend is a Angular App and I use there the [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/index.html) plugin. More or less it's kind of working, but I have troubles with the redirect URI.

When I do the Authorization Server Configuration I have to register my client application with redirectUris.

```
RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    .clientId("foo")
    .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE)
    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
    .redirectUri("https://foo.planyourtrip.travel")
    .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
    .build()
```

My problem is, that I offer the login button on different pages and I want to redirect the user to the former page after he logged in. I could register all client pages there, but some of them have a dynamic path and it would be a lot of pages. So this is not a option for me.

ATM, there is a Exception in [OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/a042a7970c6de902e23ef484edd9de941f587bea/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/authentication/OAuth2AuthorizationCodeRequestAuthenticationProvider.java#L614)

```
if (!registeredClient.getRedirectUris().contains(requestedRedirectUri)) {
    throwError(OAuth2ErrorCodes.INVALID_REQUEST, OAuth2ParameterNames.REDIRECT_URI,
    authorizationCodeRequestAuthentication, registeredClient);
}
```

I tried already to add parameters to the redirect uri, but this wasn't working too.

I'm thinking about adding a login path, where I load the origin path from a cookie, but this seems to be a lot of work and I'm surprised that there is no wildcard solution for this.

I hope someone can help me and give me some advice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide console output containing the exception

Comment: there is no console output. This is one of my biggest pain points with spring security. I just get a 400 in the browser and with my debugger, I could find the Exception :(

Comment: I prefer `angular-auth-oidc-client` to  `angular-oauth2-oidc`. [In my apps, I set `window.location.origin`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/user-proxies/blob/31340546d81471169cd7880e6504537b8dfbd09c/angular-workspace/projects/user-proxies/src/environments/environment.localhost.ts#L15) as redirect URI (so it's a sinlge redirect URI). [Auto-login guards](https://nice-hill-002425310.azurestaticapps.net/docs/documentation/auto-login) magically handle the redirection to protected pages.

Comment: Also, I prefer by far using Keycloak which allows wildcards for redirect URIs (and comes with many more features)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the `state` part of OIDC for this. The library has built in support.

For example, suppose you have an Angular guard that protects *any* route and sends people to your Auth server along these lines:

```typescript
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardWithForcedLogin implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot,
  ): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.isDoneLoading$.pipe(
      filter(isDone => isDone),
      switchMap(_ => this.authService.isAuthenticated$),
      tap(isAuthenticated => isAuthenticated || this.authService.login(state.url)),
    );
  }
}
```

The `state.url` part passed to `login(...)` should be passed along in the URL and arrive in your app again after the user gets back. You can then grab it in your login sequence and forward the user to the intended page:

```typescript
this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocument()
  .then(() => this.oauthService.tryLogin())
  .then(() => {
    this.isDoneLoadingSubject$.next(true);
    if (this.oauthService.state && this.oauthService.state !== 'undefined' && this.oauthService.state !== 'null') {
      let stateUrl = this.oauthService.state;
      if (stateUrl.startsWith('/') === false) {
        stateUrl = decodeURIComponent(stateUrl);
      }
      console.log(`There was state of ${this.oauthService.state}, so we are sending you to: ${stateUrl}`);
      this.router.navigateByUrl(stateUrl);
    }
  })
```

That way you can have just one solid "redirect" url in your Authorization Server, and persist intended route via that `state`.

You can clone, install, and run [my sample repository](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards) to see this in action.

Hope that helps!